# Creating polygon with exact measurements in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, dimensions

I want to create a square in QGIS 3 with dimensions of 50m by 50m exactly.

How can I implement that?

Answer (score 5):

You need to use a projection that supports a meter unit such as WGS 84 UTM Zone ## N/S (depending on the site location in which country, you need to specify the zone number and in which hemisphere N OR S). Then do the following steps:

- Select Advanced Digitizing Panel by right-click anywhere on the tools menu bar to enable the panel:

[image]

- Click on Add Polygon [image] to
  create a new one
- Add one vertex on the canvas to activate the Advanced Digitizing Panel to enter the dimensions:

[image]

- In the field `d` write 50 and click enter to restrict the distance to only 50 meter, then add a new vertex:

[image]

- Repeat the above process until you close your square.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Set your project to a projected grid system (not lat-long) and use the Vector... Research... Create Grid tool.

Zoom in on the map to a bit more than 50m across, choose Rectangle (polygon) and set the extent to the canvas extent. Set H and V spacing to 50.0m.

[image]

You might get a grid with more than one square. Edit the layer and delete all the polygons except one. That will be a square of 50m *in that coordinate system*.

There's probably other better ways - try the various "CAD" style plugins...

Answer (score 1):

If you need the square at a known location.

Ensure your CRS is set to a measured projection (m), like UTM.
Place the point where you want the square, you can use many locations if you like.

Run the buffer tool, setting the buffer distance to 25m (half of 50m).
In the processing toolbox search fro "Bounding Box"
Use the buffer as the input, and you will have an output of a square 50m x 50m around your chosen point location.