# Advanced digitizing tools greyed out

Tags: qgis, digitizing

I want to create a rectangle of size 3.2m x 2.1m in QGIS. My project CRS is set to WGS 84 / UTM zone 30N.

I have been following answers to similar questions asked here ([Creating polygon with exact measurements in QGIS 3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/325769/creating-polygon-with-exact-measurements-in-qgis-3)) but I cannot progress further because the options I need on the advanced digitizing toolbox are greyed out, so I cannot input the required size (picture attached below)

[image]

Does anyone know why this might be?

Answer (score 2):

Advanced digitizing tools only work with projected CRS (that only apply to the project SCR, layer can be in a projected or geographic CRS).

You are using a geographic CRS (your coordinate show as Long/Lat both in the advanced digitizing panel and at the bottom in the coordinate box).

You need to check that your project CRS is really set as WGS 84 / UTM zone 30N (epsg:32630)

Comment: Great, thanks for your help!